# Could not find com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-accounts:0.7.0. on fresh installation of MapBox

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I set up a fresh react-native project and added Mapbox with `yarn add @react-native-mapbox-gl/maps`.

This

> Notice, that if you're using the default Mapbox Android SDK (which is packed in with this lib)
> and are on newer Android OS version (API 30+),
> you'll encounter Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber.

is not applicable as far as I understand, because I am aiming at API 29 on Android. Plus, it is not the error I am getting.

I added the democode provided

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import MapboxGL from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps';

MapboxGL.setAccessToken('<YOUR_ACCESSTOKEN>');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  container: {
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: 'tomato'
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1
  }
});

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.page}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MapboxGL.MapView style={styles.map} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and started the App on Android. I get the following this error:

> Could not find com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-accounts:0.7.0.
> Required by:
> project :react-native-mapbox-gl_maps > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.1.0
> Search in build.gradle files

This is `app/android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

> FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-accounts:0.7.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-accounts/0.7.0/mapbox-android-accounts-0.7.0.pom
> - file:/Users/macosx/.m2/repository/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-accounts/0.7.0/mapbox-android-accounts-0.7.0.pom
> - file:/Users/macosx/Documents/mapstar-current/MapStar/node_modules/react-native/android/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-accounts/0.7.0/mapbox-android-accounts-0.7.0.pom
> - file:/Users/macosx/Documents/mapstar-current/MapStar/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-accounts/0.7.0/mapbox-android-accounts-0.7.0.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-accounts/0.7.0/mapbox-android-accounts-0.7.0.pom
> - https://www.jitpack.io/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-accounts/0.7.0/mapbox-android-accounts-0.7.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-mapbox-gl_maps > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.1.0

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

When I click on the link provided
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-accounts/0.7.0/mapbox-android-accounts-0.7.0.pom

I get a 404...

[image: 404]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure why (maybe because `react-native-mapbox-gl` is being updated), [this](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/android/install.md) needs to be added to your code:

Add the following to your `android/build.gradle` under section `allprojects/repositories`

```
    maven {
        url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
        credentials {
            // Do not change the username below.
            // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username). 
            username = 'mapbox'
            // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
            password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
        }
    }
```

Got this hint from here https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/1501#issuecomment-906158991

Comment: Did you come up with any other solution?
Because I have 2 very similar projects, in one of them this solution works seamlessly, but in the other the error **Could not find com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-accounts:0.7.0.** still persists and adding jcenter() into project gradle file does not help at all.

Comment: @Rickertbrandsen What I posted in the answere helped me.

Comment: @Stohpface that is unfortunate I am kind of really desperate and nothing helped even from the official github repository.

Comment: @Rickertbrandsen I am sorry that I cannot help you further. Welcome to the wonderful world of `react-native`... Try including `username` and `password` in `android/build.gradle`

Comment: @Stohpface well, to be honest i am coming from android native development (Kotlin) but for the gradle it is exactly the same for android native. These are the things I actually tried. But thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Hey @Rickertbrandsen  did you manage to find a solution I'm still on this bug.

Comment: Hey @BadrFilali, I solved it moving the maven block code  maven { _mapbox things_ } instead of build.gradle into settings gradle. There should be **repositories** "wrapper" too. But I do not know from what world you are coming.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this line in my `app/build.gradle` file and rebuilding solved the problem for me:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        jcenter()
    }
}
```